# Hooking internal function: How do the the parameters look like?

Tags: c++, function, assembly, hook, reverse-engineering

I have already been using Easyhook in C# to hook functions of the WINAPI.
Now I am trying to hook an internal function of a program to log a specific "event".

I have been able to discover the function call with the "Ultimap"-Function of Cheat Engine:

```
008AEC40   /$  6A FF             PUSH -1
008AEC42   |.  68 E37EC100       PUSH Progra.00C17EE3
008AEC47   |.  64:A1 00000000    MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[0]
008AEC4D   |.  50                PUSH EAX
008AEC4E   |.  51                PUSH ECX
008AEC4F   |.  56                PUSH ESI
008AEC50   |.  A1 4093F600       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[F69340]
008AEC55   |.  33C4              XOR EAX,ESP
008AEC57   |.  50                PUSH EAX
008AEC58   |.  8D4424 0C         LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+C]
008AEC5C   |.  64:A3 00000000    MOV DWORD PTR FS:[0],EAX
008AEC62   |.  8BF1              MOV ESI,ECX
008AEC64   |.  897424 08         MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8],ESI
008AEC68   |.  E8 033CFFFF       CALL Progra.008A2870
008AEC6D   |.  C74424 14 0000000>MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+14],0
008AEC75   |.  8B4424 1C         MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+1C]
008AEC79   |.  50                PUSH EAX
008AEC7A   |.  8D4E 24           LEA ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+24]
008AEC7D   |.  C706 18E8CD00     MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI],Progra.00CDE818
008AEC83   |.  E8 F8E7FFFF       CALL Progra.008AD480
008AEC88   |.  C74424 14 FFFFFFF>MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+14],-1
008AEC90   |.  8BC6              MOV EAX,ESI
008AEC92   |.  8B4C24 0C         MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+C]
008AEC96   |.  64:890D 00000000  MOV DWORD PTR FS:[0],ECX
008AEC9D   |.  59                POP ECX                             
008AEC9E   |.  5E                POP ESI                                  
008AEC9F   |.  83C4 10           ADD ESP,10
008AECA2   \.  C2 0400           RETN 4
```

The function gets called here:

```
008CAF5F    .  85F6              TEST ESI,ESI
008CAF61    .  74 29             JE SHORT Progra.008CAF8C
008CAF63    .  6A 32             PUSH 32
008CAF65    .  8D5424 4C         LEA EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4C]
008CAF69    .  52                PUSH EDX
008CAF6A    .  8D8F DC120000     LEA ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+12DC]
008CAF70    .  E8 2BF4F4FF       CALL Progra.0081A3A0
008CAF75    .  C68424 A4000000 1>MOV BYTE PTR SS:[ESP+A4],13
008CAF7D    .  834C24 14 40      OR DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+14],40
008CAF82    .  50                PUSH EAX
008CAF83    .  8BCE              MOV ECX,ESI
008CAF85    .  E8 B63CFEFF       CALL Progra.008AEC40    #### FUNCTION CALL ####
008CAF8A    .  EB 02             JMP SHORT Progra.008CAF8E
008CAF8C    >  33C0              XOR EAX,EAX
008CAF8E    >  C78424 A4000000 1>MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+A4],14
008CAF99    .  8B95 F0130000     MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+13F0]
008CAF9F    .  6A 01             PUSH 1
008CAFA1    .  8D7424 38         LEA ESI,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+38]
```

Right now I am trying to learn more about ASM (calling conventions etc.). [This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29527/Reverse-Engineering-and-Function-Calling-by-Addres) is very good but I still don' t know how to deal with the function above.

How might the function argument(s) look like?

When breaking at the function call, the information (a simple Integer) I try to "extract" via hooking is stored in EBX, which unfortunately isn' t accessed once. So I have look for a function, where this value is passed as an argument, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `008AEC40` appears to be using the [thiscall calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx). The first argument, the `this` pointer is passed in `ECX`. The rest of the arguments are pushed on the the stack in right to left order. This particular function, a method of C++ class, only takes one argument in addition to its implicit `this` pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know any books / tutorials to start with about reverse engineering C++ applications?